# Indoor maps - How to track user location and directions using iBeacons manual setup?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi Guys,

I am creating one demo project to track user location in indoor area and display live tracking using Estimote Proximity Beacons. And SDK use Estimote Indoor location sdk. But I am stuck at point.

SDK delegate function always send response error, and error is: 
Can't determine position outside the location

Here I am represent my code and function that i am use in my demo so please any one have idea on this please suggest me in which point i can make mistake so i will solve that and implement correct solutions. Please suggest me and thanks in advance...

```
let beaconManager = ESTBeaconManager()
let locationManager = EILIndoorLocationManager()
var location = EILLocation()
let locationBuilder = EILLocationBuilder()
var positionView = EILPositionView()
var position = EILOrientedPoint()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.beaconManager.delegate = self
    self.beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // TODO: put your App ID and App Token here

    ESTConfig.setupAppID("Id i am use Registed Estimote Id", andAppToken: "Token also use provided by register app on Estimote")
    ESTConfig.isAuthorized()

    locationBuilder.setLocationName("DCX Retail Store")
    locationBuilder.setLocationBoundaryPoints([
        EILPoint(x: 0.00, y: 0.00),
        EILPoint(x: 0.00, y: 1.00),
        EILPoint(x: 1.00, y: 1.00),
        EILPoint(x: 1.00, y: 0.00)])

    locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-255556B57FE6D", withPosition:EILOrientedPoint.init(x: 0.00, y: 0.00), andColor: ESTColor.blueberryPie)
    locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-255556B57FE6D", withPosition:EILOrientedPoint.init(x: 0.00, y: 1.00), andColor: ESTColor.mintCocktail)
    locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-255556B57FE6D", withPosition:EILOrientedPoint.init(x: 1.00, y: 1.00), andColor: ESTColor.icyMarshmallow)
    locationBuilder.addBeacon(withIdentifier: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-255556B57FE6D", withPosition:EILOrientedPoint.init(x: 1.00, y: 0.00), andColor: ESTColor.blueberryPie)

    // Add door in Indoor area...

    locationBuilder.addDoors(withLength: 0.3, atBoundarySegmentIndex: 0, inDistance: 0.7, from: .rightSide)

    locationBuilder.setLocationOrientation(0)

    //set up location...
    self.location.randomPointInside()
    location = locationBuilder.build()!

    // Set the location manager's delegate

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.start()
    self.locationManager.state(for: self.location)
    self.locationManager.mode = EILIndoorLocationManagerMode.light

    self.locationView.showTrace = true
    self.locationView.showWallLengthLabels = true
    self.locationView.rotateOnPositionUpdate = true

    self.locationView.locationBorderColor = UIColor.black
    self.locationView.locationBorderThickness = 2

    self.locationView.doorColor = UIColor.green
    self.locationView.doorThickness = 2
    self.locationView.traceColor = UIColor.yellow
    self.locationView.traceThickness = 2

    self.locationView.wallLengthLabelsColor = UIColor.blue

    //Start Location Drawing..
    self.locationView.drawLocation(self.location)
    self.locationManager.startPositionUpdates(for: self.location)

}
```

//EILIndoorLocationManager delegates methods..

```
func indoorLocationManager(_ manager: EILIndoorLocationManager, didFailToUpdatePositionWithError error: Error) {
    print("failed to update position: \(error)")
}

func indoorLocationManager(_ manager: EILIndoorLocationManager, didUpdatePosition position: EILOrientedPoint, with positionAccuracy: EILPositionAccuracy, in location: EILLocation) {
    var accuracy: String!
    switch positionAccuracy {
        case .veryHigh: accuracy = "+/- 1.00m"
        case .high:     accuracy = "+/- 1.62m"
        case .medium:   accuracy = "+/- 2.62m"
        case .low:      accuracy = "+/- 4.24m"
        case .veryLow:  accuracy = "+/- ? :-("
        case .unknown:  accuracy = "unknown"
    }
    print(String(format: "x: %5.2f, y: %5.2f, orientation: %3.0f, accuracy: %@", position.x, position.y, position.orientation, accuracy))

    self.locationManager.startPositionUpdates(for: self.location)
    self.locationView.updatePosition(position)
    lblCoordinate.text = "X:\(position.x),Y:\(position.y),accuracy:\(accuracy)"

}
```

Thanks You,
Guys.

Comment: Are you sure you have to draw exact indoor location point in indoor location app from estimote??  because i have already used estimote indoor location sdk in my app and its works great.

Comment: Could you set your location using estimote indoor location application?and store your location point in estimote cloud??

Comment: Yes,i have to store my office indoor location on estimote indoor location.

Comment: Yes, if i am working with estimote indoor location sdks and configure ibecons with cloud then it's working. but i am trying to  configure ibecons manually in this case it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, just try to recheck your indoor location point. 
You set your location using indoor location application. Try to download beacon location (if possible) from Estimote Cloud and set same values manually in your app.